# Cómo hacer un listado paginado de mi consulta SQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, lista, paginación

tengo que hacer un listado páginado de los resultados que me devuelve mi consulta SQL.
Alguna prueba que he hecho creando la navegación después no me devuelve nada al cambiar de página.
Me han comentado que debo hacer unos cálculos y adaptar los límites pero no se exactamente qué significa eso.
Creo que a parte debo mostrar el cambio de página por método get.
Espero que alguien me sepa ayudar
Gracias!

````
const REGPAG = 5;

$db = @new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$basedatos);
if ($db->connect_errno) 
    die("<p class='MSGError'>Error al conectar a la Base de datos: (".$db->connect_errno.") ".utf8_encode($db->connect_error)."</p>");

$query = "Select count(*) as total from Formato";
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($db->errno) {
    die("<p class='MSGError'>Error en la consulta:<br><br><code>".$query."</code><br><br>
        el servidor informa del error:<br><br>
        <code>(".$db->errno.") ".utf8_encode($db->error)."</code>
        <br><br>Tome nota del error para informar al soporte.</p>");
}
$Total = 0 + $result->fetch_assoc()['total'];
$NumPaginas = 2;  //calcular el número de páginas total
$LimInf    = 0;  //calcular el primer registro de la página actual
$LimSup    = REGPAG;
//calcular cuales seran las páginas primera, anterior, actual, siguiente y última
$query = "Select nombre, codigoformato from Formato limit $LimInf,$LimSup";
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($db->errno) {
    die("<p class='MSGError'>Error en la consulta:<br><br><code>".$query."</code><br><br>
        el servidor informa del error:<br><br>
        <code>(".$db->errno.") ".utf8_encode($db->error)."</code>
        <br><br>Tome nota del error para informar al soporte.</p>");
}
if ($result->num_rows == 0)
    echo "<p class='MSGInfor'>No existe ningún Lector dado de alta</p>";
else {
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while ($fila = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo("\n                                <tr>   
                        <td><a href='ForConsultar.php?txtCodigo=".$fila['codigoformato']."'>".$fila['codigoformato']."</a></td>
                        <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
                        </tr>");
        }
    ?>
</table>  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que deberias hacer es plantearte enviar una variable en la que indiques que pagina quieres obtener. Puede que estes en la pagina 1 y quieres ver la 5, (por ej). Entonces necesitas pasar un filtro indicando que quieres la pagina 5. Esto en tu url sera algo tipo:

```
http://servidor/formatos?pag=5
```

y en tu codigo, debes recojer esa pag y validarla. (que sea positiva, por ej) y si no existe, asignarle un valor por defecto. Por ej:

```
$pag = !empty($_GET['pag']) ? $_GET['pag'] : 0;
```

esto asignaria el valor de pag o un 0. 
mi recomendacion: que tus paginas vayan de 0 al total. Luego en la presentacion de los enlaces de pagina ya le añadiras un +1 para indicar la pagina 1, 2, 3...

El numero total de paginas seria:

```
$numPaginas = $total / REGPAG; // tendras que ajustar esto con ceil, o round
```

por otra parte, tu $limInf realmente es un offset (un desplazamiento de los elementos que no quieres leer). Si te indican la pagina 7(por ej) tu desplazamiento sera:

```
$limInf = REGPAG * $pag ;
```

Y con esto, ya podrias hacer tu consulta de elementos.

Para el paginador, una vez que ya tienes el total de paginas, puedes hacer un bucle desde 0 hasta $total -1, para generar los enlaces:

```
for($cont=0; $cont<$total - 1; $cont++) {
    echo '<a href="http://servidor/formatos?pag='.$cont.'>pagina'.$cont.'</a';
}
```

Echa un vistazo a https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx/ para ver como funciona el offset y el limit en una consulta.

Comment: De acuerdo he añadido lo que me has dicho pero ahorano  consigo poner el navegador que me permita seleccionar el número de página a la que quiero ir. Espero que me puedan seguir ayudando

Comment: ```$Total = 0 + $result->fetch_assoc()['total'];
$NumPaginas = $Total / REGPAG;  
$pag = !empty($_GET['pag']) ? $_GET['pag'] : 0;
$LimInf    = REGPAG * $pag;  
$LimSup    = REGPAG;
$query = "Select nombre, codigoformato from Formato limit $LimInf,$LimSup";
$result = $db->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows == 0)
    echo "<p class='MSGInfor'>No existe ningún Lector dado de alta</p>";
else { ```

Comment: ```<?php
 for ($cont=0; $cont<$Total - 1; $cont++) {
  echo '<a href="http://GestionBiblioteca/Formato/ForListadoPagidnado.php?pag='.$cont.'Página'.$cont.'</a';
}
  while ($fila = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo("\n        <tr>   
      <td><a href='ForConsultar.php?txtCodigo=".$fila['codigoformato']."'>".$fila['codigoformato']."</a></td>
      <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
      </tr>");
  }
 
?>

</table> ```

Comment: En tu último comentario no estás cerrando bien los enlaces de gestionbiblioteca. Revisalo, falta poner el > del primer $cont

Comment: Vale he solucionado lo de los enlaces. Ahora lo que pasa es que mi navegador de páginas no me devuelve las otras páginas.